How do you map Razor Page static assets to a custom folder and require authentication
UPDATE: I've solved the mystery behind my second question, but my first is still pending. I can't find a way to change where the static assets are published, without modifying it post-build. I was hoping for a project config entry or something similar.

I have a .NET 6.0 Web Application using Razor Pages, which is using the default wwwroot as the web root directory to server static assets. These files are, as expected, publicly accessible.
The application uses a standard page structure as follows:

MyWebApp

custom-root
wwwroot
Pages

ContainingFolder1

PageOne.cshtml
PageOne.cshtml.cs
PageOne.cshtml.css
PageOne.cshtml.js


ContainingFolder2

PageTwo.cshtml
PageTwo.cshtml.cs
PageTwo.cshtml.css
PageTwo.cshtml.js
PageThree.cshtml
PageThree.cshtml.cs
PageThree.cshtml.css
PageThree.cshtml.js







When publishing the application, the static assets are published under wwwroot:

CSS files are combined via CSS Isolation and stored at wwwroot/MyWebApp.styles.css
JS files are stored at wwwroot/Pages/ContainingFolderX/PageName.cshtml.js

My client has requested that the "sensitive" content (namely calling out the JS files that have endpoint information) be secured so they are not publicly available. Our application is secure even if these endpoints are known, but the goal is to obscure this information on top of it.
Based on this requirement, I would like to do two things:

Publish the static assets to a custom folder (such as "custom-root" in the above example, at the same directory level as wwwroot). Ideally, I only need to move the JS files, but I'm willing to move all of them if necessary. (I have no idea how to accomplish this, right now I've been copying them post-deployment for testing)
Add a second (or multiple if needed) static file configuration after adding authentication middleware to the pipeline.

I tested moving the "app.UseStaticFiles(); line after the app.UseAuthentication(); line to verify that my intentions. This works successfully, except for the fact that now my unauthenticated pages cannot access CSS and JS content (as expected).
I then tried to add a second static file option to the pipeline as, as specified in the Microsoft docs (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-6.0) but with no luck:
public static class Program
{
    var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

    ...

    var app = builder.Build();

    ...

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();

    app.UseStaticFiles(); // serve public files from wwwroot

    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
    {
        FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(builder.Environment.ContentRootPath, "custom-root")),
        RequestPath = new PathString("/Pages"),
    }); // serve files that require authentication

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
        endpoints.MapRazorPages();
    });

    app.UseRequestLocalization("en-US");

    app.Run();
}

What I expected was that the second instance of UseStaticFiles would capture requests of the following format and serve them from my custom location.
https://www.mywebsite.com/Pages/ContainingFolder1/PageOne.js
However, I am instead receiving a 302 redirect to my custom "PageNotFound" endpoint (presumably because it is still checking for the content at wwwroot and not finding it, then my custom 404 middleware is redirecting to my not-found page).
EDIT: I tried adjusting the above code based on feedback as follows (removed some of the other snippets to keep this shorter):
public static class Program
{
    var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

    ...

    // Modified this first instance of UseStaticFiles to ensure it is not used for my custom request route
    app.UseWhen(context => !context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/Pages", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase), appBuilder =>
            {
                appBuilder.UseStaticFiles();
            }); // serve public files from wwwroot

    app.UseAuthentication();

    app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
    {
        FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(builder.Environment.ContentRootPath, "custom-root")),
        RequestPath = new PathString("/Pages"),
    }); // serve files that require authentication

    ...
}

This successfully stops the static file requests for my target path (/Pages/ContainingFolderX/PageName.cshtml.js) from being served from wwwroot, but I still receive a 302 to my NotFound handler page. I would suspect that the authentication/authorization middleware is causing a problem when executed first, but as mentioned, moving the entire default "app.UseStaticFiles();" call to after authentication works without issue (besides not serving my anonymous pages, of course).
Update for question 2: After a little research I discovered that the below code appears to look for an exact match on RequestPath (not "Starts With"):
    app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
    {
        FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(builder.Environment.ContentRootPath, "custom-root")),
        RequestPath = new PathString("/Pages"), // Path must exactly match "/Pages"
    });

To solve this (without explicitly mapping all directorys under /Pages), I leveraged the "UseWhen" method suggested by Qiang Fu to do the following:
app.UseWhen(context => !context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/Pages", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase), appBuilder => // Request path starts with anything but the target route
{
    appBuilder.UseStaticFiles();
}); // serve public files from wwwroot

...

// Do other stuff like authenticate

app.UseWhen(context => context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/Pages", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase), appBuilder =>
{
    appBuilder.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
    {
        FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(builder.Environment.ContentRootPath, "custom-root")),
    });
}); // serve public files from "custom-root"

This accomplishes what a need from a file-serving perspective, but I still don't know how to deploy my static assets to the custom folder. Right now I'm moving the target files to the custom location post-deployment.
All I could find was potentially this property group property: "", but this is only mentioned in the Blazor documentation (which I'm not using) and doesn't seem to do anything for my project (doesn't even break the build/publish - it just is ignored).

You could try branch the middleware pipeline to conditionally usestaticfiles:
app.UseWhen(context => !context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/pages"), //determine if not start with "/pages" 
    appBuilder =>
    {
        appBuilder.UseStaticFiles();
    });

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(builder.Environment.ContentRootPath, "custom-root")),
    RequestPath = new PathString("/Pages"),
}); // serve files that require authentication

Just note that UseWhen will rejoin the main pipline while Mapwhen doesn't. 
Reference:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-8.0#branch-the-middleware-pipeline

I was hoping there was just something wrong with the way I set up my 2nd static files configuration, but I was suspicious it was never being considered. I'll give this a try this morning as a test. Any thoughts on how I can have the static assets deployed to a different directory (rather than moving them post-deployment)?

I was able to confirm that your suggestion prevents the pipeline from falling into the first static file handler, but it still returns a 302. So it looks like there is something wrong with the way I'm trying to add the custom folder, or for some reason it's getting caught up elsewhere in the pipeline, but I wouldn't know where - not that would result in a redirect to not found. Updating my question with these findings.
